Assuming the equivalent of the AdS/CFT correspondence were exact in our universe, why do we think we live in the bulk rather than in the boundary?
The question is self-explanatory, why would we think/perceive that we are living in the 3D bulk rather than in the 2D boundary? Why is our perception universally biased? is it about physics or is it about biology/evolution? I am assuming the two theories would be mathematically equivalent, so being in the bulk or in the boundary should be similar to having two different interpretations of the same mathematical theory without any physical or experimental consequences.
We should be able to switch our perception/understanding of the world back and forth from either one, which is not the case.  Is it possible that an extraterrestrial civilization instead evolved perceptual sensors that makes them think the opposite, that they live in a 2D world described by the physics of the boundary? Am I missing something obvious?
Actually, because locality in the boundary corresponds to non locality in the bulk and vice versa,  may be such organisms are out there in the universe but invisible to us because they are scrambled. But this would imply the existence of at least two kinds of beings in the universe, which may be able to communicate with each other if they had advanced tech to unscramble the signals, but would normally be invisible to each other, due to the fact that one organism is local in the bulk and the other on the boundary, that is, they are not look local to each other but spreaded out relative to each other in an irreconocible mess.

It is a soft question and not a personal theory, I don't get the down vote, mean anonymous stranger, I am just asking about the implications of the holographic correspondence

I understand, engineer minded physicist  (likely an oxymoron) usually vote down these kind of questions, they hate any kind of speculation, or interpretation of theories. Still, I appreciate the calculations you do, even if that is the only thing  you do, they are very useful to advance tech.

Hi, I am the third downvoter. I downvoted because your entire question seemed (to me) to come from a simple misconception. Indeed, you seem to want to use the AdS/CFT to our universe, which is asymptotically dS, not AdS. To me, this question is too hypothetical to be useful for anyone but you. Do not take the downvote personally, I judged a question, not a person. (and I am not engineer-minded).

@JeanbaptisteRoux Thanks for your clarification. It was likely my fault, I was unclear, I am aware of what you said, and by "equivalent' I meant assuming the correspondence also holds for our dS universe. But that might be too speculative at this point. I still think it is a fair question, but it might technically  break the rules about being mainstream physics.

Note that the dS/CFT is an actual thing. There are two approaches I am aware of. The first one is given by Strominger https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106113 . The second one uses the static patch of de SItter space-time and the cosmological horizon is the "holographic screen" https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.12861 (I have not the time to re-read carefully so I may be a bit off in my description). Finally, there is a last instance of de Sitter/CFT holography which you can find in my first article, but it is quite new...

The premise of the question is far from being established. It is not clear that AdS/CFT directly applies to our world.
However, there is still an interesting point this question brings up. Namely, there are many mathematical statements and equivalences in physics, that are true but not obvious. An example would be the equivalence between Newtonian, Lagrangian, and Hamiltonian mechanics. I think most people intuitively grasp the idea of Newtonian mechanics; forces act on particles, and particles respond to forces. But even though Lagrangian mechanics is equivalent, can you really say that you can flip to "experiencing the world from the principle of least action"? Not writing equations down, but perceiving a particle picking the path of least action. Or, can you flip to a Hamiltonian point of view, where the 3 dimensions of space we observe are only half of the story, and momenta are treated on equal footing as positions as coordinates in phase space?
My feeling is that we have evolved to think of the world in terms of concepts that are useful for our survival, based on our senses. We experience the world in position space, time ticking one instant after the other. So maybe it's not surprising that formulations of mechanics that are manifestly local, focus on positions, and evolve from one moment in time to the next are more intuitive to us, even though there are mathematically equivalent formulations that are somehow "spread over time", or treat position and momentum on equal footing. The reason mathematical reasoning is useful in physics, is at least partly because these connections are not obvious to us, and appealing to rigor can counteract our limited intuition based on experiences in a small corner of the parameter space of the world.
Given this human difficulty in intuitively grasping equivalent formulations of the relatively mundane arena of classical mechanics, I don't find it surprising that we would have a difficult time grasping a much more abstract quantum duality, assuming it is relevant for our world (which, again, is not clear).

There's maybe another way to put this. The AdS/CFT duality interchanges strong and weak coupling; when the gravity side is weakly coupled (meaning quantum effects are small), the boundary side is strongly coupled, and vice versa. Our intuition comes from a world where quantum effects are small, so perhaps it is natural we would find a description in terms of a weakly coupled theory more intuitive. Certainly it is easier to calculate. The gravitational fields we experience are weak, so if something like AdS/CFT were to hold, we would expect the boundary gauge theory to be strongly coupled, with very strong and weird quantum effects, which would be a description much less directly tied to our experience.

Thanks, I agree with your answer to the first part, we cannot easily switch between perceiving alternative interpretations, most likely  might involve abstract objects beyond our capacity to perceive them. But regarding the second half or the question, I would like your opinion regarding the possible logical existence of beings that are localized in the boundary (|assuming the QFT physics in the boundary allow the evolution of such beings. If so, we would live in the same universe but be mostly invisible to each other, right? or I am making a silly assumption here?

@PatoGalmarini Generically the dictionary between the boundary and bulk is highly nonlocal. I'd expect a generic observable that is "simple" from the point of view of the CFT, would be complicated in the bulk. However, beyond that, I don't have any opinion about the possibility of conscious beings on the boundary or how they would look to bulk observers.

Thanks! ........

I am curious, is it because you don't find interesting thinking or speculating about it,  or is it because it is too difficult to give an informed opinion due to the complexity of the subject? (or some other reason, for instance, being afraid of being downvoted by mean guys who see physics closer to engineering rather than to philosophy)

@PatoGalmarini Closer to "too difficult to give an informed opinion." I don't care if I get downvoted, except right now my score is a multiple of 5 which I like :) Studying physics, I've learned the world is very complex, and it's very easy to be wrong, so when speaking scientifically I don't like to speculate on areas where I don't have at least some evidence to justify what I'm saying. Consciousness, in particular, seems like a rabbit hole that is very difficult to make sense of.

If you forced me to have an opinion, I'd probably say that for a QFT to describe something as complicated as life, it would need to break conformal invariance like QCD does, so strict AdS/CFT wouldn't apply. But, going with a more general "there's some gravity holographic dual to this QFT" idea, I'd guess that a QFT dual to our world must be so strongly coupled and quantum and "strange" that any form of "life" that is naturally described in those terms must be very alien. I'm skeptical it exists, or that if it exists we'd be able to understand it. But, my confidence on this is very low!

well, we can replace consciousness by some evolved AI like unconscious agent that attempts to organize its perception using math. But I am not going to insist, thanks a lot for you answers, I really appreciate them.

Thanks for you last opinion, it is very useful to me, I am still a few years to understand the subject at a level I could have my own opinion, assuming I could ever get to that point.
